# Enable/disable a plugin individually per sales channel

Tags: shopware, shopware6

We have a plugin with a lot of custom routes, services, decorators, etc.
Is there a relatively simple solution to enable/disable the plugin individually per sales channel?

The only solution I found is placing if conditions everywhere, but that would be insane for plugins with the size of my example.

I haven't found anything about that topic here on stack overflow or somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not easily achievable due to the way the underlying PHP and symfony framework works.

Especially the PHP `opcache` and the caching of symfony's DI-Container play a role here. As all requests to your shopware server are answered by the same code base, those caches include your plugin for every sales channel.

Additionally I would advise against trying to achieve something like that because it can easily lead to inconsistensies between the sales channels.

But themes can be activated per sales channel, as you want to completely customize the UI/UX for each sales channel, maybe that could be a solution for you, to solve the problem/differences on the theme level.

The business logic and workflows should be the same for each sales channel, because else you may run into problems where you can't distinguish between the sales channel (e.g. for Admin-API requests).

Comment: I slightly disagree with your last sentence. Those inconsistencies are sometimes exactly what you want, because the different saleschannels can be two completely different shop "frontends" with completely different functionalities.

Comment: The UI/UX can be completely different for each sales channel, but the business logic should stay the same, otherwise to be safe it should probably be two different shops that may connect to the same ERP or something like that.

Exactly that is the different between Themes and Plugins, Themes are for UI stuff and you can activate those per sales channel, plugins are for businesss logic and should be activated globally.